# ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Tags: python

I am trying to run this project (https://github.com/unitedstates/congress#readme) and am having trouble with the command `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and getting the error `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`. I've been trying out some solutions but in the end, when I try to run it, it says `./run` not found. How do I install the right packages.

I am running Mac M1.

Comment: are you in the right directory?

Comment: Did you clone the Github repo?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized that I cloned it incorrectly and wasn't in the right spot. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clone your project (you can save it anywhere).

Make sure you have homebrew installed.

Make sure to enter into the Congress folder of the project you just cloned in the terminal.

Then run `python3 -m venv congress source congress/bin/activate`

Then `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` The requirements.txt file will be in the main congress folder.

After that you can use `./run govinfo --bulkdata=BILLSTATUS ./run bills`  to run bills or `./test/run` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `requirements.txt` file in this repository, so it will be installed from `setup.py` automatically.

You can install directly the package in the repository folder:

```
pip install -e .
```